# Style input range with shadow dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to style `input type range`  - to change `background-color` of the input, and change the apperance of the slider button `(width, height, color`). So far I've managed to change the `background-color` of the input, but I can't find the way to select that slider button. I guess that it has to be done with shadow DOM, but can't figure out how.

```
<input id="my-range" type="range">

#my-range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #592A71;
    width: 45%;
    height:15px;
    margin:30px;
}
```

[Here is the example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ua9av9b/1/)

Comment: @Noy Gabay added link

Comment: @itsgoingdown there isn't any standards for HTML5 inputs aditional parts as are arrows in date picker and number or slider or other... https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow-dom you're looking for [can be found here](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html), here's an example (copied from the link):

```css
input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    border: 1px solid white;
    
    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 300px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    
    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;
    
    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input id="my-range" type="range">
```

Answer (score 1):

The button that is hanging on `range input` is called a thumb. And this is how you select them.

```
Webkit/Blink - input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb
Firefox - input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb
IE - input[type=range]::-ms-thumb
```

Sample

```css
/* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: red;
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="my-range" type="range">
```

*References:*

[Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

[Other Link](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html)